# WinForms floating windows (like Delphi7 IDE)

Tags: winforms, delphi, ide

I want to setup my WinForm to look like the Delphi7 IDE. Basically that means the window has no background (the desktop shows through), and child windows float around.

Here's a sample image:
[image]

I can handle the floating windows, but how would I go for the main window (the menu bar and the toolbar)? What are the WinForm properties required to get this layout? I can't seem to be able to get rid of the window's client area.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why can't you get rid of the client area?  Just resize the main form so that it's as thin as you can make it.

You may be implementing the floating windows as UserControls in the main form's Controls collection.  If so, there are two ways you can deal with this:

1. Implement the floating windows as actual windows.  Show them using "frmToolWindows.Show(this);" (this will keep them always on top of your main form).
2. If you need to keep the floaters as UserControls, you can make the client area of your main form transparent by setting the form's TransparencyKey property to some arbitrary color (Color.Red, for example) and then setting the form's BackColor property to the same color.  This will make your form transparent and able to be clicked through.

Comment: Thanks. Getting rid of the client area by resizing the mainform is indeed the way to do it, however, that comes with some other details. When you resize the window you can expose the client area again, and when you maximize the window then it will occupy the entire screen and the client area will hide the desktop.

The solution to both problems above is to handle WM_SIZING and WM_GETMINMAXINFO messages and limit the height as required.

Regarding floating windows, I detest the second option as it adds unnecessary burden. Your first option is a good one. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You don't necessarily want the other windows always on top of the main window. That can the main window's toolbar hard to access.

Answer (score -4):

Please don't make a UI like this.  It is very non-standard, and doesn't gain anything in the realm of usability.  You could simplify things by keeping it all in one window like Visual Studio.

Comment: The down-votes are because the question wasn't "should I make my UI like this?" Also, I actually prefer this style of IDE (from my Visual Basic days) on my laptop, as the current Visual Studio layout requires a big monitor to be most effective.

Comment: I can handle a down-vote, if it increases the overall usability of software.

Comment: @John: Unfortunately it doesn't increase the usability of the software to confine everything to the client area of the single main window. Ask any user with multiple monitors how they feel about it. And Visual Studio users have indeed been wishing for better multi monitor support, for years.

Comment: John, you wouldn't get down-votes on this if you'd posted it as a comment to the question, where it belongs. The answer section is for things that actually answer the question that was asked.

Comment: Actually, VS 2010 is implementing something alike it because it's multi-monitor friendly, unlike applications that keep everything within a window.

Comment: In my case I have to go with this UI style because my app relies on showing other apps windows and allowing you to drag-drop stuff from my window to other apps' windows. If I have a solid client area then users will have to either keep alt-tabbing or resize my app's window to a minimum to coexist with other windows, or have multiple monitors.

Comment: This user interface is definitely not required for multi-monitor support.  Separating the toolbar from the rest of the app is the main difficulty, and there just isn't a great reason for it.  Two (or three) containing windows (one for each monitor) could achieve all the same goals, without splitting each panel into separate floating windows.  And Visual Studio is doing it right by allowing the user to decide how his windows work: floating, docked, document, etc.

Comment: @Wouter: The question was tagged Winforms first.